# Custom split function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

I am trying to create a "split" function in SQL Server that splits a string and gives me the n'th substring, but I just don´t have enough SQL experience to implement it.

Ideally I would like to write

```sql
select splitselect('level_a:level_b:level_c:level_d',':',3)
```

and it would return "level_c".

Parts of the answer is here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

but I am having trouble translating that into the functionality I want.

Comment: I recommend [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). But, truthfully, I suggest you fix your design.

Comment: I recommend doing that outside of SQL Server entirely. String manipulation is not SQL Server's strong suit. That's not what it's designed to do. If you really really have to do it in SQL, I think that an XML / Json based solution might be the best option for this (Hint: You might not need to split the string at all)

Answer (score 0):

Use StringSplit function but must be sql server 2016 or above
STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator )
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('John,Jeremy,Jack',',')

Comment: That couldn't get the n'th item because the result of the built in string split is a table without an index column meaning you just get an unsorted set of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you want
The speed is the same as the SQL build-in /System function `STRING_SPLIT()` function.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[fnVRS_STRING_SPLIT]','IF') IS NULL BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnVRS_STRING_SPLIT] () RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT 1 X') 
END
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnVRS_STRING_SPLIT]
(
    @string    nvarchar(MAX), 
    @separator nvarchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS RETURN
   WITH X(N) AS (SELECT 'Table1' FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) T(C)),
        Y(N) AS (SELECT 'Table2' FROM X A1, X A2, X A3, X A4, X A5, X A6, X A7, X A8) , -- Up to 16^8 = 4 billion
        T(N) AS (SELECT TOP(ISNULL(LEN(@string),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 N FROM Y),
        Delim(Pos) AS (SELECT t.N FROM T WHERE (SUBSTRING(@string, t.N, LEN(@separator+'x')-1) LIKE @separator OR t.N = 0)),
        Separated(value) AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, d.Pos + LEN(@separator+'x')-1, LEAD(d.Pos,1,2147483647) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - d.Pos - LEN(@separator)) 
                               FROM Delim d
                              WHERE @string IS NOT NULL)
       SELECT s.value
         FROM Separated s
        WHERE s.value <> @separator
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that is what you want

```
create FUNCTION dbo.SplitArrayIndex
(
  @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
  @Delimiter VARCHAR(50) ,
  @index INT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Items TABLE
        (
          id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
          Item NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )

    IF @Delimiter = ' '
        BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
        END

    IF ( @Delimiter IS NULL
         OR @Delimiter = ''
       )
        SET @Delimiter = ','


    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @DelimIndex INT

    SET @ItemList = @InputString
    SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
    WHILE ( @DelimIndex != 0 )
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT  INTO @Items
            VALUES  ( @Item )

        -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex + 1,
                                      LEN(@ItemList) - @DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
        END -- End WHILE

    IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in 
    @InputString
        BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT  INTO @Items
            VALUES  ( @Item )
        END

  -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return 
  @InputString
    ELSE
        INSERT  INTO @Items
        VALUES  ( @InputString )


    SELECT TOP 1
            @ret = Item
    FROM    @Items
    WHERE   id = @index
    RETURN @ret

END -- End Function
```

Comment: This is probably the worst way to split a string in SQL Server. Read Aaron Betrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for more information.

Comment: A `WHILE` is a terrible solution. There are *far* better ways to split a string, such as an XML Splitter ([Splitting Delimited Strings Using XML in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/)), A Tally Splitter ([`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)), CLR functions, JSON String splitters and the in built `STRING_SPLIT` function. a `WHILE` is a looong way down the list as a option.

Comment: I still dislike parts of the article, @ZoharPeled ,as the information on Jeff Moden's splitter isn't a true comparison. His (Jeff's) splitter intentionally doesn't support `MAX` data types, but all the comparison on it in the article are using an altered `MAX` version; causing the performance to be much lower than it could be.

Comment: @Larnu Jeff and Aaron discuss this at length in the comments to this article. I do agree that using `varchar(8000)` is a hell of a lot faster than using `varchar(max)` for this - but still, it's the best SQL Server string splitters performance-comparing article I know about...

Comment: I know they do, @ZoharPeled;it just would have been nice if Aaron had revisited it with a `MAX` and non-`MAX` version. People don't often read the comments and so consume what is effectively incorrect information.

Comment: I'll also add that Aaron's test data has a very low cardinality, which strongly favors XML.  Most things that you need to split doesn't work out so well with XML, especially because of the concatenation people have to do to get it into an XML format.

Comment: @ Zohar Peled ... Read the following article and see that the XML splitter is actually one of the worst (unless it's already in XML format to begin with).  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function